React - A base64 PDF file displays well in the Edge browser, but in the Chrome browser it shows a string with an open button
I'm trying to display a PDF page with the following code:
<embed
src={processedData}
width="100%"
height="800px"
style={{ border: 'none' }}
type="application/pdf"
/>

processedData is a file converted to base 64, a very large string.
In print it looks like this:
'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiWhs8XXDQoxI..........'
In the Edge browser the file displays fine, but in the Chrome browser I get the attached image.
I'm writing in React js.
I've tried many of the solutions suggested here but without success.
I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Based on the comments here I changed the code:
<iframe
src={pdfUrl}
width="100%"
height="600px"
style={{ border: 'none', marginTop: '10px' }}
title="PDF Viewer"
/>

pdfUrl = "blob:http://localhost:5173/8997509d-0c6c-473d-b158-2ac5ce08b828"


But it remains the same.

Thanks, I tried these two:
<embed src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf"></embed>

<iframe class="pdfobject" title="Embedded PDF" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" allow="fullscreen" ></iframe>

And I got the file name again with an open button.
